# Get the login info of short connections in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, session

I want to store the login info in SQL Server and I am using

```
select * from sys.sysprocesses
```

It works in most time. But when I meet a short connections, the connection info will be deleted from `sysprocesses` when the query in short connections has finished, and then I cannot get the login info  from the `sysprocesses`, so how can I get the login info of a short connection, except using the native trace file audit.

Comment: Use [logon trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) perhaps?

Comment: what details do you need? Just that someone logged in and the time or do you need other info? If it's just basic login and time/date info, you only need to enable that option from SSMS (properties, security, login auditing). If you want login/logout you can use SQL Server audit (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280448.aspx) which is pretty lightweight. Logon triggers work too but you need to be very careful with its implementation as you can block users from logging in via logon triggers.

Comment: I need to check some critical action on specific table, and who did it.Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: What does "critical action" mean? And what does this have to do with logging this info? If you are wanting to trap which Login is executing a DML or DDL statement, that is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `sys.sysprocesses` as it was deprecated 10 years ago when SQL Server 2005 was released.

You should get this info (and more) from the following 3 DMVs:

- [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx)

In order to get this information to store without needing to constantly poll every few seconds (which is error prone), you should use a Logon Trigger (introduced in SQL Server 2005). For info related to those, please see:

- [Logon Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx)
- [Capture Logon Trigger Event Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213611.aspx)
- [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to trap actions on a particular table (and not just trap connection info for ALL connections), then you can trap DML events on the particular table and DDL events for the database containing that table. Please see:

- [DML Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx)
- [DDL Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx)
- [How to find the stored procedure which executed an event?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111924/how-to-find-the-stored-procedure-which-executed-an-event/111933#111933) (this is an answer of mine to a question on DBA.StackExchange that shows an example of capturing DDL event info for a particular table, including the Session ID / @@SPID which can be used when querying the 3 tables noted at the top of this answer -- this is the most accurate way of capturing the info as trying to match up monitoring info of the event with disconnected login info is definitely error prone).

Comment: Thank you, I will check it.But will the logon triggers block the user login action?And does it work on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: @BinXu I suppose it could block if it is a long-running trigger. Or you have the option to cancel the Logon event (prevent the person from logging on) by issuing a `ROLLBACK`. I updated my answer with the version that this feature started in, but please read the links I posted as they have all of the info you are asking about. Also, please answer my question in a comment on your Question related to what you are really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is the first time I use stackoverflow. The critical action means update the data in a specific column and some other DML and DDL statements.

Comment: @BinXu If that is what you want to track, then a LOGON TRIGGER will not help you. You need to use DML and DDL triggers to trap those events. And in that case, you will always get the correct connection info as it is all part of the same transaction. Which makes me wonder how you are doing it now such that information is not available in `sysprocesses`.

Comment: I can get the sql statement from another monitor device, and I need to map all these sql statements with the login info.

Comment: @Begisue I updated my answer again with more info. Matching info from two separate monitoring processes doesn't sound very reliable. You can capture the event and the connection info at the same moment in the process that the event is occurring in, so why bother with anything less accurate?

Comment: The reason is if I use the triggers, there will be too many triggers on a table.So I can only get the statements from another monitor

Comment: @Begisue How many triggers do you have? You can simply add a query to an existing trigger to capture the connection info for that event. And the DDL triggers are on the database, not on the table.

Comment: Some table will check all of the write and read actions for each column; and all kinds of the DDL actions for some databases.